# Mistakes in .htaccess file, trying to overwrite HTTP header settings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I have a SFTP access to a web space with these settings:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: Apache
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 7864
x-frame-options: sameorigin
content-security-policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.mydomain.com; font-src 'self' *.mydomain.com
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

On this web space, I uploaded a web page (HTML and CSS only, with OTF fonts). Now, I want to embed this web page as `iframe` on another website.

Currently, it doesn't work because of CORS. Because I have no access to the server settings, I would like to do it with the `.htaccess` file.

I read [this](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/apache-web-server/modifying-http-headers) article, and thought about creating a `.htaccess` file with a content like this:

```
X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://the-page-with-my-iframe.com/
Content-Security-Policy: no-restrictions
```

How is it possible to write that correctly?

Would be very thankful for help!

<3

Comment: Those are not valid configuration directives. So the configuration file you created is invalid. You should see a clear error in your http server's error log file.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you for your answer! Yes, it's invalid. That's why I ask how it is possible to write it correctly.

Comment: First hit on google for "X-Frame-Options: allow-from": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options ... I'd say after a glance there that you are probably looking for something like `Header set X-Frame-Options "allow-from https://the-page-with-my-iframe.com/"`...

Comment: I have already read this article. But it doesn't help me to solve this issue. Everything makes sense, but I just don't know how to do it. I would need a fitting code or a tutorial.

Comment: Well, if you read it, then why did you implement something else?

Comment: And if you confirm that your code is invalid, then what _does_ your http server's error logfile actually say?

Comment: FYI: This is _not_ CORS.

Comment: I'm desperate :(

Answer (score 0):

The `x-frame-options: sameorigin` header allows framing only in the site's own domain. Therefore just remove this header.

If you wish to have protection aganst clickjacking, use `frame-ancestors` directive in your Content-Security-Policy header:

```
content-security-policy:
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.mydomain.com;
  font-src 'self' *.mydomain.com;
  frame-ancestors 'self' https://the-page-with-my-iframe.com;
```

Note. The `script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'` rules makes you CSP very ineffective against XSS. Think about use 'nonce-value' instead of `'unsafe-inline'` and do you really need `'unsafe-eval'`...